# Recover the files from ubuntu

Tags: data-recovery

I had installed ubuntu 11.10 from windows 7, the same was mistakenly uninstalled during 14.04 installation.

Is there any way to get the files from uninstalled ubuntu 11.10 (kept the files in Desktop, Downloads)

please help.

Answer (score 0):

Please re-check your files.

I suggest that you install recovery programs from **Ubuntu Software Center**.

[image]

If you are aware of magic number of deleted files, you can use magicrescue(Recovers files by looking for magic bytes) as the same way above.